# how to move one component to another component on button click in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, reactive-programming

could you please tell me how to move one component to another component on button click in react ?
I get the `react-router.js` from cdn .I don't know how to use this js ..I want to show `second component on button click of`first component` here is my code

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jVoZjW?editors=1010

```
class Abc extends React.Component {
  handle(){
    alert('move to second component')
  }
   render (){
     return (<div><h1>second</h1><button onClick={this.handle}>move to second page</button></div>);

   }
}
class Pqr extends React.Component {
   render (){
     return (<div><h1>second</h1><button>click</button></div>)

   }
}
class Sqr extends React.Component {
   render (){
     return <h1>third</h1>
   }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Abc/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: When you say "move" do you mean "show"?

Comment: yes to to show second component using router js

Comment: Not sure you're understanding the use-case of React-Router. React-Router is meant for when you change the url, to show a different hierarchy of components. If you're not changing the route (url), then you shouldn't be using React-Router.

Answer (score 2):

There is many ways this can be accomplished, all of which have there place. This is but one of many methods:

I left an alternitive to this answer aswell this answer on the codepen:
http://codepen.io/dirtyredz/pen/gLJeWY

```
class Abc extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={first: true};
  }
  handle(){
    alert('move to second component')
    this.setState({first: false})
  }
  render (){
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handle.bind(this)}>move to second page</button>
        {this.state.first == true && <Pqr/>}
        {this.state.first == false && <Sqr/>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Pqr extends React.Component {
  render (){
    return (<div><h1>First</h1></div>)
  }
}
class Sqr extends React.Component {
  render (){
    return <h1>Second</h1>
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Abc/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

This is a quick example, like i said earlier others may be better but this works as expected.

Comment: i want to do using RouteHandler