# Show different component when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, render

I just want to **render different components when I click the button**.

I'm not using class, rather using functional **React Hooks**. This not a whole thing but a piece of it so the main issue is rendering new components using the same approach.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import { Second } from "./components/secondpage";

function App() {
  const handleClick = () => {
    // I tried using html in place or returning component but nothing happpened
    return <Second />;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <h1>Create Account</h1>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

//this is in second.js
export const Second = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>welcome to second page</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

// I tried using this but nothing worked
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={Second} />
  </Router>
);

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of routing, refer this link : https://codeburst.io/getting-started-with-react-router-5c978f70df91 or by changing the state. refer this link : [how to move one component to another component on button click in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41318668/how-to-move-one-component-to-another-component-on-button-click-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

Why you need a router for showing the component you can set a variable then show   on the basis on that if you need to show the component after click the button. and in router code by default router is the  component. Please check the router concept first.
Or if you want to use the router only then on link,native link and many more you can pass the value to show the components.

You can do this something like this:

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  NavLink
} from 'react-router-dom';

import './App.css';
import { Second } from './components/secondpage';

export default () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <nav className="navbar  ">
        <div className=" navbar-collapse"  >
          <ul className="navbar-nav">
            <li className="nav-item">
              <NavLink to="/second">second</NavLink>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/second"
          exact
          render={() => {
            return (
              <div>
                <h1>welcome to second page</h1>
              </div>
            );
          }}
        />
        or
        <Route path="/second" component={Second} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `React Router` or use `Conditional Rendering` to call different components on button click.

Here is an example using `router`, Make sure to install `react-router-dom` first and import necessities:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Switch,Route,Link} from "react-router-dom";
```

and inside return method, use this:

```
 <Router>
            <nav>
              <ul>
                <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/users">Users</Link></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>

            <Switch>
              <Route path="/about"> <About /> </Route>
              <Route path="/users"> <Users /> </Route>
              <Route path="/"> <Home /> </Route>
            </Switch>
          </div>
    </Router>
```

Using `Conditional Rendering` and using `states`:

1. Initially set state to `false` (say `isTrue` is our variable)
2. on Button Click  -> inside the method you will call (here it would be `handleClick`) set state to true.

Now in return method:

```
<div>
    {
     this.state.isTrue ?
     <div> <YourComponent /> </div>:
      <div>  
        <h1>Create Account</h1>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    }
</div>
```

On a similar thought, checkout these:

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html